# Getting errors from a proxy server I'm not using

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, proxy, opera

So many months ago I tried to set up a proxy server, found it too slow for my needs so I unchecked the box in LAN settings marked 'use a proxy server etc..'  Now whe. I try to go online I get 'cannot connect to proxy server'. And the box is still unchecked.  I have no idea how this is even close to possible.

Comment: Your browser might be still using old proxy settings. Check in your browser settings.

Comment: I did.  If you read the question you would see that the proxy is off in the browser settings, unless there is another place where there are proxy settings that o don't know about

Comment: Well there is the system wide proxy connection that most browsers pickup which is accessed via Internet Explorer menu `Internet Options>Connection tab>LAN settings`. I am assuming you are using chrome which has its own chrome only proxy settings under `Advanced Settings`.

Comment: The proxy setting in chrome takes you to the same system window that you describe.  'Change proxy settings' takes you to the 'connections tab' you describe.

Comment: It probably looked different due to my pc theme then. Can't help you there. Maybe try a different browser.

Comment: The problem persists on chrome, ie and opera

Answer (score 0):

So what ended up working is I changed the settings to 'automatically detect settings and turned the machine all the way off and then back on again and it seems to be fine for now.